# Repeat array with array_slice

Tags: php, arrays

I just want to do one thing, I have an array with products, lets say like this (in simple way):

```
$products = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k');
```

I am outputing that products in a slider (showing 3 products), and I have arrows (left and right).

Primary I am on page 1 (`$page = 0;`), and using `array_slice($products, $page * 3, 3);`, so it will return:

```
array('a', 'b', 'c');
```

When I click arrow right, it will show:

```
array('d', 'e', 'f');
```

Next:

```
array('g', 'h', 'i');
```

Next:

```
array('j', 'k');
```

And here is the point and my question. I want on this page to return `array('j', 'k', 'a');`

How can I do it in the simpliest way?

PS: array with products is generated dynamically.

PPS: I also want to do it in other direction, ie. when I click left arrow, and I am on the first page, I want to return `array('i', 'j', 'k');`

Any ideas are appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getPortion($products, $page, $per_page)
    {
    $index = $page * $per_page;

    // to get always positive module
    $real_index = ($index % sizeof($products) + sizeof($products)) % sizeof($products);

    $return = array_slice($products, $real_index, $per_page);
    while (sizeof($return) < $per_page)
        {
        $return = array_merge($return, array_slice($products, 0, $per_page - sizeof($return)));
        }
    return $return;
    }

$products = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k');

// 0 page
echo json_encode(getPortion($products, 0, 3));
// ["a","b","c"]

// 3 page
echo json_encode(getPortion($products, 3, 3));
// ["j","k","a"]

// -1 page
echo json_encode(getPortion($products, -1, 3));
// ["i","j","k"]

// 0 page, but per_page larger than array length.
echo json_encode(getPortion(array('a', 'b', 'c'), 0, 5));
// ["a","b","c","a","b"]
```

[Demo](http://3v4l.org/l8JGB).

Comment: Excelent. The nicest solution. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`array_slice()`](http://php.net/array_slice) to get the required length from both ends of the array and then merge it with the original array, like so:

```
$lengthToExtend = 3;
$first = array_slice($products, 0, $lengthToExtend);
$last = array_slice($products, -$lengthToExtend, $lengthToExtend);
$products = array_merge($last, $products, $first);
```

[**Demo.**](https://eval.in/70552)

Comment: Thanks, now when I am thinking about that again, I can see the solution, like you wrote. But I am thinking, how it will be done, on next page, after `array('j', 'k', 'a');`... Then I will need to get `array('b', 'c', 'd');`, and so on...

Comment: @Legionar: Then just increase `$lengthToExtend`? [(See demo)](https://eval.in/70557)

Answer (score 2):

My crazy solution:

```
<?php
$products = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k');

$perPage = 3;
$offset = 9;

if ($offset >= count($products)) $offset = 0;

$page = array_slice($products, $offset, $perPage);

if (count($products) <= ($offset+$perPage)) {
    $page = array_merge($page, array_slice($products, 0, $perPage - count($page)));
}

print_r($page);
```

[Demo at Ideone.com](http://ideone.com/BcgLhR)

Comment: Are you sure, this will work? It doesnt look like - when you `$offset = 0;` it will cause a problem...

Comment: Offset should be in 0..count($products) range, then it works fine

Answer (score 2):

All you need to know here is where to begin. The same way its done backwards by replacing `reset` with `end` and `next` with `prev`

```
<?php 

$a = array_map('chr', range(65,90));

$start = 22; 

# init
$i = 0; while($i < $start) { next($a); $i++; }

# for example, do this three times
for($j = 0; $j < 3; $j++)  { 
    $f = [];
    for($e = 0; $e < 3; $e++) {

      $c = current($a);

      if($c === false) {
        $c = reset($a);
      }

      $f[] = $c;

      next($a);

    }
    print_r($f);
}
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/70615)**

**[DEMO(backwards)](https://eval.in/70660)**

Answer (score 0):

This is more simple, I guess... works perfect for me

```
$products = array_chunk($products, $limit, true); // true if you want keep keys
$products_sliced = $products[$page-1];
```

Comment: This will of course not work... When on the last page, it will not return `array('j', 'k', 'a');`...